# program is stuck on taskbar while shutting down windows

Tags: c#

I have built a program with C# and the program keeps running on system tray near the windows clock. When I try to shut down windows, the program is still running and shutting down windows get stuck.

This is not a program with Windows 7.So my question here is how to add 'something magic' to allow windows to shut down?

Comment: To prevent windows from shutdown or to allow windows shutdown? Anyway check the main forms FormClosing and Closed events

Comment: sorry. it is to allow windows shutdown

Answer (score 1):

In your form closing event you have to catch windows closing message.[FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) has a property named [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx). An example is shown below

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;// or Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```